# Word wrapping in pango with mixed scripts

Tags: text, unicode, arabic, unicode-string, pango

I have a text box implementation that uses pango.  If i put a string that starts with a word in right-to-left script, followed by a space, followed by word in left-to-right based script, the word wrapping that pango uses gets messed up (using `PANGO_WRAP_WORD_CHAR`).  For the string *العربية ENGLISH* I get the following:

[image: Bad word wrapping]

If I add the unicode character `U+200F` after the space, then I get the expected word wrapping:

[image: Expected word wrapping]

Also, if I replace the Arabic script above with Hindi (which is left-to-right like the English next to it) then I still get the problem, so it doesn't seem to be a strictly left-to-right, right-to-left thing.  In the Hindi case, I put in a hack that inserts a `0x200E` after the space it resolves the problem.

Is this a bug in pango?  Are there work-arounds I can try that are generic enough to fix the problem but not break other cases?  The current work around I'm using inserts either a `0x200E` or `0x200F` after every space based on the direction of the previous strongly directed character in the string, but I'm not sure if there's certain strings that this will cause problems with.

Update: I was able to reproduce this problem on Ubuntu 12.04 with gedit (with *Enable Text Wrapping* and *Do no split words over two lines* settings enabled).  I simply typed `Hello world` over and over until it wrapped several times, then replaced all instances of `world` with `पहुंचगया`, and everything collapsed to a single line.

Comment: the issue pango things that an LTR word after RTL word (or the inverse) as one word, so it will not break it on two if you choose wrap on words.

Comment: I updated the question to mention that the problem also occurs when I have only LTR scripts alternating (e.g. English and Hindi)

Answer (score 5):

The symbols `U+200F` and `U+200E` are RIGHT-TO-LEFT and LEFT-TO-RIGHT Marks. S:

- between each english text and arabic text, put  a RIGHT-TO-LEFT mark
- between each arabic text and  english text, put a LEFT-TO-RIGHT mark

It is a bug because Pango should this automatically in viewing text but as Pango isnt doing it, you should do it manually.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to figure out if this is a bug in pango or if these symbols are required.  If I put the same text in a microsoft word text box or a Qt text edit box, then the results are what I expect (look like the bottom picture).

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me a bug or not complete feature as it appears on mixed scripts.

Seem to me you are using an old pango development, may be from Ubuntu 12.04?

```
Ubuntu 12.04 contains Gedit 3.4
Ubuntu 15.10 contains Gedit 3.10
```

Pango has radical change in 3.6, it has replaced his shaping engine with HarfBuzz. [[2]](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointFive/Features/Harfbuzz)

I couldn't reproduce the bug using Gedit 15.10, it always moves (2) two words down, also it does not allow me to resize its window to try splitting those two words. See screen-shot.

[image: pango shaping mixed scripts in gedit]

**Update:**

It seems its behavior has changed:

- It does not wrap the 1st word from English script when start with Arabic.

  ```
  pango-view  --text "وقعت أطراف سياسية ليبية اليوم في المغرب اتفاق سلام برعاية أممية aljazeeranet" --width=70 --margin=0 --wrap=word
  ```

  [image]
- It same as previous case, does not wrap, and enforce the width

  ```
  pango-view  --text "elections الجزيرة" --width=30 --margin=0 --wrap=word
  ```

  [image]

**References:**

- [Port pango to Harfbuzz](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointFive/Features/Harfbuzz)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  After your post, I've tried this in ubuntu 15.1's gedit and I get the same result (using the hello world test case I mentioned above).

Comment: I also am not sure what version of pango ubuntu 15.1 is using.  Searching for pango from `/usr/lib`, the only pango library I see is `libpango-1.0.so.0` (and some others with similar versioning)

Comment: @pauld , ok I could reproduce it, I didn't notice `--wrap=word`, as your question was clear about `word-char` wrapping mode. Same behavior in Ubuntu 15.10. So this answer is irrelevant  for the problem I will remove it later. I should add its not just with `U+200F` & `U+200E`, but any control char make the english word wrap. what i have tested so far `U+202C`, `U+061C`, `U+202A`, `U+2069` , and same thing happen when swapping English word 1st then Arabic 2nd.

Comment: @Sneetsher, I think your answer is relevant as it shows how to reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Note, we recently upgraded the version of pango we used, from pango version 1.36.1  to 1.38.1, and this issue went away.  So I believe this was a bug in pango or harfbuzz that has since been fixed.